# Getting Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch in cognito idp settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito

I am following this [cognito add social auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html) to add google auth into one of my app for testing. Completed all steps as listed, but when I am testing that using this
https://<your_user_pool_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com , I am getting an error

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://xxxx-xxxx.auth.ap-south-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit:
```

initially the redirect uri and callback url in cognito app client settings were different but i changed those, also I tried changing my redirect url to simple https://google.com, but still not working. I did some research regarding the same, found out that it might take some time to reflect the changes in google oauth setings, its been 2 hrs since I have changed the same, should I wait or is there some other work around this.
Also, I setup facebook login following same doc, it is working fine.
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, redirect url in google auth credentials needs to be your `**domainName+/oauth2/idpresponse**` .

Comment: could you add more precision ? Where di you add it in Authorised redirect URs Authorised Javascript origin ? and what do you mean by  domainName+/oauth2/idpresponse ? Because it is what you used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this mismatch refers to the difference between your constructed URL and the setting in Cognito Pool. In the pool config, the `redirect_uri` is called `Callback URL`. Make sure those two have the same URL.

You can set it in Cognito UI here: `App Integration > App Client Settings > Sign in and sign out URLs > Callback URL(s)`

or you can specify the URL(s) in your code if you are using CDK.

```
new cognito.UserPoolClient({
  oAuth: {
    callbackUrls: ['https://www.example.com', '<url2>'],
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: They both are same, have mentioned it in the question itself, google's redirect uri and cognito's callback uris both are same, tried https://google.com as well at both place.

Answer (score 0):

its has something to do with your uri, whether in google cloud or cognito ,double check if the uri entered is a match

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I think the OP solved the problem the same way I did. But their answer isn't too clear. So what I had to do is add an URI under 'Authorized redirect URIs' for my google app on GCP (Select your project -> Credentials -> Authorized redirect URIs). The URI is

```
https://{my-domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/ipdresponse
```